# file lock between two programs

Tags: python, c, file

I am looking for the proper way to lock a file between two programs.

I have one program (C) which processes and writes results to files at a rather fast rate (writer/high priority). I wrote a user interface in Python to plot/monitor these data (reader/low priority). I would like to avoid opening the file in Python as it is being written since that would produce a biased plot.

So far I was simply doing `f = fopen( filep, "w" );`
and `f = open( filep, "r" );`

Then I have gone through some examples to set up a file lock:

```
fd = open( fp, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY );
if( fd < 0 ){
    printf("failed to get fd\n");
    return -1;
}

_lock.l_type = F_WRLCK;
_lock.l_start = 0;
_lock.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
_lock.l_len = 0;
_lock.l_pid = 0;

if( fcntl( fd, F_SETLKW, &_lock ) < 0 ){
    printf("fcntl failed to set lock\n");
    return -1;
}
```

but this modifies the file permission.

An advisory lock should be enough since I can control everything in the two programs using fcntl.

Could someone provide an advice to create an efficient lock and respect the natural priority between the two programs?

Comment: it is unclear from your question, but if you have a C producer and a Python consumer (or vice-versa), use a pipe and there are no lock issues.

Comment: If you control both programs, why not use a pipe?

Comment: thanks for your inputs,
I know how to pipe between two subprocesses in the same C program. How would you pipe between a C program and a python program? is that even doable?

My data files represent data sets very different from each other and they must not be misidentified. Would you then use one pipe for each data set?

Comment: Yes, pipes are the same.  Set up a named pipe from the first program, and open it with the file system name from the other one.  Use some sort of an ID tag and a single pipe.